# What means "write access violation" in C and how do I solve this?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

**So I am completly new to the C language.**
I come from a Visual Basic and C# background, languages where I usually don't need to care about low-level stuff. Recently started to learn about pointers and I am doing some of the leetcode challenges to get some practice.

**Here is the challenge text: **
Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

**Here is my attempt:**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {
    if (strsSize == 1) return strs[0];

    if (strs[0] == "") return "";

    char* result = strs[0];
    size_t result_length = strlen(result) - 1;
    char* result_end = strs[0] + result_length;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < strsSize; ++i) {
        
        size_t length = strlen(strs[i]) - 1;
        
        if (length < 1) return "";
        
        if (length < result_length) {
            result_end = strs[0] + length;
            result_length = length;
        }

        char* temp1 = result;
        char* temp2 = strs[i];

        while (*temp1 == *temp2 && temp1 < result_end) {
            ++temp1;
            ++temp2;
        }

        if (temp1 < result_end) {
            result_end = temp1 - 1;
            result_length -= strlen(result_end) - 1;
        }
    }

    *(result_end + 1) = '\0';
    
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* a[3];
    a[0] = "flower";
    a[1] = "flight";
    a[2] = "flow";

    char* b = longestCommonPrefix(a, 3);
    printf(b);
}
```

Why do I get a write access violation error on the line `*(result_end + 1) = '\0';` ?
Googling this I found articles saying c strings are readonly, why tho and what would be a work around?
Also any general C tips or links to such things are appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:**
Thanks @Chris for the solution.
Here is my new code which works just fine. Also thanks at @@WeatherVane for a general C tip, I also included his knowledge into my new code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {
    if (strsSize == 1) return strs[0];

    if (strs[0][0] == 0) return "";

    char* result = _strdup(strs[0]);
    size_t result_length = strlen(result) - 1;
    char* result_end = strs[0] + result_length;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < strsSize; ++i) {

        char* str = _strdup(strs[i]);
        
        size_t length = strlen(str) - 1;
        
        if (length < 1) return "";
        
        if (length < result_length) {
            result_end = str + length;
            result_length = length;
        }

        char* temp = result;

        while (*temp == *str && temp < result_end) {
            ++temp;
            ++str;
        }

        if (temp < result_end) {
            result_end = temp - 1;
            result_length -= strlen(result_end) - 1;
        }
    }

    *(result_end + 1) = '\0';
    
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* a[3];
    a[0] = "flower";
    a[1] = "flight";
    a[2] = "flow";

    char* b = longestCommonPrefix(a, 3);
    printf(b);
}
```

Comment: I get no compiler warnings and the program prints `fl`. But this `if (strs[0] == "")` is not the way to compare strings in C. You must use `strcmp()` or in this case, check `if (strs[0][0] == 0)`

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe you have a different compiler, I use Visual C(Visual Studio).
And thanks for the tip with the string comparison.

Comment: Using MS Visual C 64-bit 2022 (without IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you've written to some memory you shouldn't.

In `main` you have an array of `char` pointers. But each points to a string *literal* which is `const char *`.

In `longestCommonPrefix` you then attempt to modify these string literals, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

If you wish to modify these values in your `longestCommonPrefix` function, you should copy these string literals into allocated memory. The [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) is a very straightforward way to do this, as long as you ensure you free the dynamically allocated memory afterwards.

```
char *a[3];
a[0] = strdup("flower");
a[1] = strdup("flight");
a[2] = strdup("flow");
```

If you're tools don't allow use of this function, you can either declare `a` to hold 3 fixed length strings, or manually handle the dynamic memory allocation and copying.

Comment: For legacy reasons, the type of a string literal in C is an array of `char`, not `const char`, and it is automatically converted, where appropriate, to `char *`, not `const char *`. Students should not be taught to expect `const char *` because they cannot rely on the compiler catching mistakes through the type qualifiers. The C standard does not define the behavior if a program attempts to modify a string literal. That means it is avoided in portable code, but it also means a C implementation can support modifying a string literal if its implementors desire.

Comment: Possibly the most dangerous thing code with UB can do: work as expected.

Comment: Note that `strdup()` becomes a part of Standard C in C23 (as does `strndup()`).

Comment: Thanks all for the information.  @Chris your solution works just fine but for the leetcode challenge I do not have access to the main so I just added that to the function. Also I got a warning strdup is deprecated and I should rather use _strdup cause it is ISO standard. 
Anyway thank you very much. I will add my new code to the question for clarity.